# USB ports of USB-C dock (HP G5) stop working when unplugging/replugging

Tags: usb-c, docking-station

I have a Dell XPS 9560 notebook running Windows 10 and the HP G5 USB-C dock to which I've added a monitor, an ethernet cable and several USB cables (for keyboard, mouse, webcam, etc).

It was working perfectly in the beginning, but since a few weeks the USB devices stop working when I unplug the USB-C cable and later plug it in again. The monitor works fine, charging works fine, but the USB devices are not seen by the computer anymore.

Happens every time now, and is fixed by rebooting the computer. Removing the dock from power to reboot it does not help.

I read about similar issues with Dell's own dock and tried to update/reinstall several drivers, but nothing has helped so far.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Do you eject the USB device before unplugging?

Comment: @harrymc Usually not, but I've tried that as well, didn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: @harrymc It appears that ejecting the USB device *does* work, not sure why it didn't work when I tried it before! Could you turn your comment into an answer so that I can mark it as the solution to my problem? Thanks

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The poster has indicated that the problem was solved by ejecting the USB device
before unplugging.

Although the latest Windows 10 versions have changed the policy of the disk to favor
less caching in memory of the data written to the disk, this does not mean that
ejection is no longer necessary.

In addition, in some rare cases where lots of writes were done to the disk, the
disk LED lights might still blink for some time after the ejection.
This means that the disk has not yet finished all write operations,
so better wait for it to stop before unplugging.